# Magic system question: Uses for containment field based magic. Individual uses? Societal uses? Technology examples?

Tags: magic, society, technology, tools

I'm working on a high fantasy setting with a few magical elements - this being one of them.

The basic premise for the way the magic works is the ability to create an orb of force around any material. The orb can then be contracted or expanded which would increase or decrease the pressure within the orb, without changing the volume inside. This would allow for heat changes and phase changes for things like water to ice or steam.

The story context for this is that an enslaved group of humans overthrew their dictators. The dictators were a shadow species who were immortal but intangible and dependent on humans to move stuff around for them, etc. They prized a special kind of stone that was the only material they could actually touch - and this was used as the resource to create "containment bubbles" and trap the shadow-folk.

So this magic would be more of a technology accessible to anyone who could use a special tool.

The question is what would be some cool applications for this technology?

Some ideas:

- Turn water to ice
- Generate heat through expansion (pressure law)
- Turn carbon into diamonds
- Carrying or moving orbs of material
- Piezo electronics
- Transportation of materials

Are there everyday uses? Industrial uses? Civil engineering uses?

Comment: I do not understand how you can expand an orb without changing the volume inside.  Doesn't expanding a thing mean it is bigger?  When I expand my lungs (prior to delivering a loud Bronx cheer) the volume of my chest increases so much that the snaps on my shirt all fly open.

Comment: Does an orb require the caster to maintain it continuously? E.g. could an old lady store jam in an orb and leave it in her basement for 3 weeks without having to think about it every moment? If the caster dies do their orbs remain? Can a caster create an orb anywhere they can conceive of, or are there limits? Can a caster have more than one orb active at one time? Can an orb be physically moved around by external forces, or does it stay exactly where the caster left it no matter what? Could someone create a black hole by creating an orb around a mountain and then shrinking it to r=0?

Comment: Is that "special kind of stone" relevant to the question? It's fine if it's just background, but I'm wondering if there is a relationship between force-orb magic and the stone, because if there is, that could also impact the ways this magic could be used in everyday life.

Comment: It seems like you are fishing for ideas, and you don't have a clear criteria for picking the best answer, except the "something cool" concept which is highly opinion based. I recommend you get familiar with what our [help] says about what to ask and what to ask not here

Comment: If you're after a more conversational approach, there's our complete list of [Worldbuilding chatrooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=worldbuilding.stackexchange.com), "The Factory Floor" being the main one (an allusion to Magrathea from THHGTTG.), but there's plenty of active ones on particular topics. You're not far off the 100 rep points needed to start your own on any topic you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not much, except power the entire world.

Wether it is wind/water mills, combustion engines or the turbines of a nuclear power plant, it all relies on the differences in entropy to generate useful force. In this case pressure. You can also use it for control and containment of materials, useful for research or keeping certain materials in place. We know little about certain high-temperature resistant materials due to how we don't have containers to heat them in and learn about those properties it has.

This all becomes even easier if you can create partial containment. That way you can have a valve on one end that releases the energy you stored by compressing something.

Comment: It is custom to not accept an answer until 24 hours have passed, that way people from all over the world can answer your question. Accepting mine now discourages them from answering, and they could have a better, more detailed answer than I do!

Comment: Okay, thanks for being so humble Demigan. I'll undo the selection and wait a bit. I liked your answer a lot though!